# I need some help on saving pictures to android in a dynamic folder

Tags: android, save, image

This is my current code: http://pastebin.com/YFAv45bD

I want to be able to save "Bldg Front(Before).jpg" in a specific folder lets say "day1" for example the name of the folder. Right now it just scattered in the public folder(the .jpg's files)

```
File picturesDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
.....
.....
private File imageFile;
.......
.......
.......
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.gcpic1:
        imageFile = new File(picturesDirectory, "Bldg Front(Before).jpg");
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent1, 1);break;
    case R.id.gcpic2:
```

I just want a simple "addtional code" for this, to add to what I already have.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save it there, maybe this could help: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html
a directory is created like that there:

```
File dir = this.getDir("name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```